# Deploying Master Branch Code from Bitbucket on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, bitbucket, commit

I currently have a merged, master branch with the code on Bitbucket. My two developers recently pushed two commits and then went off into the sunset, leaving me to deploy their code.

- I went to Heroku, and typed $ `Heroku Login` into the Terminal.
- Then put in my credentials and was approved
- cloned the most recent code into my local machine
- did $ `cd  code_name_here`
- deployed my changes off the terminal by typing $ `git push Heroku master`.

I then went to the domain to check the changes but the changes from my developers most recent commits did not show up.

So, I went back to Bitbucket, checked that all the commits were on the master branch, did the deploy again and saw that the all the most recent changes were already pushed.

Does anybody know what could be going on here?

Comment: Do you have these commits in your local clone of the repo?

Comment: Yes, I cloned them from the terminal into a folder, then deployed that. It should be in my local machine? I'm sorry, I'm actually a UX designer so this is super confusing for me.

Comment: When you push to Heroku it needs to build your application, and it gives useful output back to you in the terminal. Did you wait for that process to complete? Did the text that got sent back indicate success or failure?

Comment: The terminal indicated that build was complete and I made sure of everything before I closed the terminal.

Comment: Try opening in incognito, might be a caching issue.